# Showing error message as "Sorry, Ubuntu 16.04 has experienced an internal error"

Tags: 16.04

I am beginner to Ubuntu OS.
Yesterday I have successfully installed 16.04 version.

Today I was trying to install "ttf-mscorefonts-installer", I was getting continuously error message:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/cache/apt/archives/
```

So I have removed lock file and tried to re-configured.
Somewhere I did mistake, not getting how to resolve it.

```
root@guest-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:/# sudo apt-get install --reinstall ttf-mscorefonts-installer
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
root@guest-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:/# sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
root@guest-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:/# sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
root@guest-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:/# sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
root@guest-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:/# dpkg --configure -a
root@guest-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:/# sudo dpkg --configure -a
root@guest-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:/# sudo apt-get clean
E: Could not get lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/cache/apt/archives/
root@guest-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:/# sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
root@guest-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:/# sudo apt-get clean
root@guest-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:/# sudo apt-get install --reinstall ttf-mscorefonts-installer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 18 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 29.5 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse amd64 ttf-mscorefonts-installer all 3.4+nmu1ubuntu2 [29.5 kB]
Fetched 29.5 kB in 0s (66.9 kB/s)                    
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
(Reading database ... 212382 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.4+nmu1ubuntu2_all.deb ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.4+nmu1ubuntu2_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.4+nmu1ubuntu2_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@guest-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:/# sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
root@guest-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:/# sudo apt-get install --reinstall ttf-mscorefonts-installer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 18 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/29.5 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
(Reading database ... 212382 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.4+nmu1ubuntu2_all.deb ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.4+nmu1ubuntu2_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.4+nmu1ubuntu2_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@guest-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:/# sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]
Hit:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]    
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [68.0 kB]
Get:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]  
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [41.4 kB]
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [32.1 kB]
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [37.0 kB]
Get:9 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [306 kB]
Get:10 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [181 kB]
Get:11 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [134 kB]
Get:12 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [162 kB]
Get:13 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,516 B]
Get:14 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [3,328 B]
Fetched 1,273 kB in 3s (364 kB/s)                                           
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
root@guest-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:/# sudo dpkg --configure -adpkg: error: dpkg status database is locked by another process
root@guest-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:/# sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: error: dpkg status database is locked by another process
root@guest-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:/# sudo apt-get install -f
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
root@guest-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:/# lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1001/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
synaptic 4350 root   11uW  REG    8,2        0 14155947 /var/lib/dpkg/lock
root@guest-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:/# lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1001/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
root@guest-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:/# ps cax | grep PID
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
root@guest-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:/# kill PID
bash: kill: PID: arguments must be process or job IDs
root@guest-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:/# #wait
root@guest-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:/# kill -9 PID
bash: kill: PID: arguments must be process or job IDs
root@guest-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:/# ps cax | grep PID
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
root@guest-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:/# sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
root@guest-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:/# sudo dpkg --configure -a
root@guest-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:/# sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  ttf-mscorefonts-installer
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 18 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 134 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
(Reading database ... 212381 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing ttf-mscorefonts-installer (3.4+nmu1ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for update-notifier-common (3.168.3) ...
root@guest-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:/#
```

Now I am getting error for 16.04 internal error message.
P.F.A.

[image]

[image]

Comment: When do u see the above message???

Comment: That error message appeared when I have run the command "sudo apt-get install -f". But after restarting system, I didn't found that error again. I am not sure whether that error has been fixed or not.

Comment: This lockfile is placed for a reason. You are not supposed to delete it, but to wait until other processes (synaptic in this case) using the dpkg/apt database are done and have cleared the lock file. This usually happens after the application is closed.

Comment: it should have been fixed automatically...